# I'm making an web application but pushing a string to other browsers doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm new to Web Development and I got a problem with pushing a string data in real time with JavaScript, HTML5, and the Firebase.

I have a string 'result' and a have a span id = span1. 
It works well with following code. the 'result' shows well in my browser.

```
span1.innerHTML = linebreak(result);
```

But, I have to show the string 'result' for all clients connected to my web application. So I modified Firebase chat application example like below:

(I already have an ul id="msg" and var messageList = $('#msg');)

Giving the 'result' to function displayText()......

```
displayText(result);
```

and

```
function displayText(message) {
    var content = message.val();
    messagesRef.push({ content: content });           
}

messagesRef.limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var message = data.content;

    var messageElement = $("<li>");
    messageElement.text(message);

    messageList.append(messageElement);
    messageList[0].scrollTop = sttList[0].scrollHeight;
});
```

But it doesn't work!

String 'result' still works well with span1.innerHTML, but nothing shows on my messageList! 
I want to show the string 'result' to everyone on my web application!

Comment: I can't see what's going wrong from the snippet above. Can you set up a reproduction on jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Thank you for your reply. And I'm sorry for late. I'm in East Asia.
I just made a reproduction on jsfiddle here.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/zazen/syx1dvba/2/)
** http://jsfiddle.net/zazen/syx1dvba/2/ **

Comment: And I'm really sorry for the dirty codes on the link...
I'm really new to web development..
I want to push the STT results to other users so they could see the STT results..

Comment: The fiddle you've provided looks like an entire app, not an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will help us to isolate and understand the problem. Also, this code is running before the DOM is fully loaded and ready, which could cause innumerably problems. There are too many moving parts here for us to be of help.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136344/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-error-on-firebase, which (if not a duplicate) is highly related