# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error on firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm very new to web development and I have an error with firebase error.

I'm using Firebase and jQuery to make an web application which recognizes voice and translates it to text. (Speech-to-Text, STT)

I have to push the STT results in realtime so that all clients could see the text.

However, the problem occurs in this event listener:

```
finalSTTField.click(function (e) {
        var message = finalSTTField.val();
        sttRef.push({ text: message } );
    });
```

As a result of STT, a string is in the finalSTTField which is declared like below:

```
var finalSTTField = $('#final_span');
```

And I want to push the string by using the firebase:

```
var sttRef = new Firebase('https://sizzling-torch-2935.firebaseio.com/');
```

and

```
<div class="sttResultContainer">
    <ul id="sttMessages"></ul>
</div>
```

with

```
var sttResults = $('#sttMessages');

sttRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val();
        var sttText = data.value();

        var messageElement = $("<li>");
        messageElement.text(sttText);
        sttResults.append(messageElement);
        sttResults[0].scrollTop = sttResults[0].scrollHeight;
    });
```

But nothing shows in sttResults.

The error message on chrome browser is: 
firebase.js:26 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Error count increases every time the click event occurs. (Strangely, the count starts at 10)

The first STT transcripts are showing well in the #final_span span. 
But I have to push the string in #final_span in realtime...

Somebody help me please! It's my first web application...

Full source code is here:
[full source in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zazen/7nxacagn/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
var sttText = data.value();
```

After you call `val()` on the snapshot to get the value, you get a JSON object. No methods are defined on that object. Your text is instead in a child property, so you can get it like:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
var sttText = data.text;
```

Note that it is fairly easy to find such a problem, if you put a `console.log` statement after extracting the data:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
console.log(data);
```

This is a *very* common troubleshooting technique. In your fiddle it prints:

> Object {text: ""}